# I want to put on winter tires

Tags: tires, swap

I just bought a 2019 Camry with summer tires (215/55/R17)  I have winter tires (215/65/R17) Would it be ok to switch in the winters?  Safety and performance wise.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all 4 tires are the same size it won't hurt the vehicle.

The winter tires are the same width but about 43mm or 1.7in taller. This will slightly throw off your speedometer making it read a little slower than you are actually traveling.

Normally the thought is to have thinner winter tires, not taller. Being thinner helps slightly increase traction whereas taller doesn't change traction. That being said, with the winter tires being what they are, they will offer better traction.

I would consult your vehicle's manual to make sure that you aren't going outside the bounds of the recommended tire sizes. For example if the winters are too tall they could rub on the wheel well.

Comment: Great answer,  it may be helpful to explain why thinner is better.  Two excellent resources for tire and wheel size are - https://www.tacomaworld.com/tirecalc  - You can enter in two tires sizes and it will give the specs and show you the side by side view. Another - https://www.wheel-size.com/  -  for finding the wheel size and bolt pattern for any vehicle. (*NOT affiliated with either*)